# jQuery: make a div fadeOut + .live() + .delay() functions merge

Tags: html, delay, fadeout, jquery

Hi all
I want this div to dissapear when it show up. 
It is working now this way, but since sometimes the div is added after a load() I would need to merge it somehow with a live() I guess....

```
//Fade out the result alert.

$('.Alert').delay(6000).fadeOut(500);
```

Any ideas of how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is the div added to the page?

Comment: The div is not added by jQuery. Lets get to the point. 1) I click one link. 2) A form is loaded in a div. 3) When the user submits the form, I use $.ajax() to get the result 4) The result is displayed in the same div where the form was. I want THAT div to dissapear. I think this helps a bit more. I get the .Alert div by ajax() not adding it by jQuery.

Comment: Then, how the form is loaded in the div? and is the div already present and the form append into it or both appears?

Comment: @Chouchenos: Hi, sorry for the delay. I dont get much in this. Well, the form is loaded via .load() in the ExternalContent div. When the user clicks the submit button, I used .ajax() to get the results and load them in the ExternalContent div, without having to reload the page. Well, the result is an alert div with some message: like form submited successfully!. I want that div that appears after the users submits the form to dissapear... The ExternalContent div already exists.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you add your div to the page after the `load()`.

After you add the element to your page, add the handler or function you want them to have.

Example :

```
$('<div class="Alert"></div>').appendTo('body').delay(6000).fadeOut(500);
```

[Live example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Tb6bs/)

Comment: Just to address inevitable confusion with `.delay()`: it adds a delay to the animation queue. It *does not* "pause" execution of the code right there. It's *not* a `Thread.Sleep(6000)`. The rest of that line and subsequent lines will not be delayed--just the animation effects they may trigger will be delayed.

Comment: Indeed, but I'm sure (at least, I hope) the OP was already aware of that, since he used it.

Comment: The div is not added by jQuery. Lets get to the point. 
1) I click one link.
2) A form is loaded in a div.
3) When the user submits the form, I use $.ajax() to get the result
4) The result is displayed in the same div where the form was.

I want THAT div to dissapear.

I think this helps a bit more. I get the .Alert div by ajax() not adding it by jQuery.